# Cuando uso SASS, dejan de aplicarse los estilos

Tags: css, web, sass, scss, estilos

Estoy aplicando SCSS mediante Node a una de las páginas de mi sitio, pero al compilarlo me arruina la configuración de estilos (o sea, mi página deja de verse tal y como la había diseñado). Ya chequié que la ruta esté bien, También probé con Live SASS Compiler, pero nada funciona

Comment: Hola seria bueno que nos compartas imagenes adicional revisa que este bien linkeado recuerda que tambien puedes usar CSS conmun para verificar que este tomando correctamente el archivo de estilos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.